# Kafka connect jdbc sink SQL error handling

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently configuring a Kafka JDBC sink connector to write my kafka messages in a Postgres table. All is working fine except the error handling part. Sometimes, messages in my topic have wrong data and so the database constraints fail with an expected `SQL EXCEPTION duplicate key`...

I would like to put these wrong messages in a DLQ and to commit the offset to process the next messages, so I configured the connector with

```
"errors.tolerance": "all"
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "myDLQTopicName"
```

but it does not change a thing, the connector retries until it crashes.

Is there another configuration I'm missing? I saw only these two in the confluent documentation

(I see in the [jdbc connector changelog](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/changelog.html#version-10-1-0) that the error handling in the *put* stage is implemented in the version 10.1.0 (CCDB-192) and I'm using the last version of the connector 10.5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["The Kafka Connect framework provides generic error handling and dead-letter queue capabilities which are available for problems with [de]serialisation and Single Message Transforms. When it comes to errors that a connector may encounter doing the actual pull or put of data from the source/target system, it’s down to the connector itself to implement logic around that."](https://rmoff.net/2019/10/15/skipping-bad-records-with-the-kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-connector/)

If the duplicate key are the only type of bad records you need to deal with, you might consider use [`upsert` in `insert.mode`](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#writes)